# TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'flash'

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting the following error while using Node.js and Express. Here are my versions :

```
Node : v0.8.8
Express: 3.0.0rc3
```

The following error is obtained while trying to access the page :

```
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'flash'
    at routes (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/apps/authentication/routes.js:23:8)
```

I've tried to remove the app.use(app.router); from the app.js with no success. Here is the code that causes the error. See req.flash line.

```
app.post('/sessions', function(req, res)
{
    if(req.body.user == 'piechief' 
        && req.body.password == '12345')
    {
        req.session.currentUser = req.body.user;
        req.flash('info', "You're logged in as #{req.session.currentUser}");
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        req.flash('error', "Those credentials were incorrect. Try again.");
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }
});
```

Here is the interesting part of my app.js :

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: "DBBD6BE563419EDB0E5CBD228E603D4AD232CE05434B4FA95C6908B64EA515C3",
    store: new RedisStore({
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: "6379",
      db: "mydb"
    })
  }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
});
```

Any idea please? I've took a loof at the [Express'flash documentation](http://extjs.github.com/Connect/flash.html) and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved it for me

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/61

Now my passport app.configure looks like this:

```
app.configure(function (){
    app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
    app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());
})
```

Answer (score 25):

`req.flash` has been [removed as of 3.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x):

> - `req.flash()` (just use sessions: `req.session.messages = ['foo']` or similar)
> - [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) can be used as middleware to provide req.flash()

Comment: Thanks! Also, for the people who want to know how to use the connect-flash middleware, here is an [Express 3 example]https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/blob/master/examples/express3/app.js.