# NodeJs req.flash method not available on some requests

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to use the `req.flash` that was [removed as of Express 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121887/typeerror-object-incomingmessage-has-no-method-flash).  According [the docs](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash), simply configure the app as so to use it:

```
 app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
});
```

However, I've configured my app as so:

```
app.configure('production', function() {
    app.use(express.static('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/lib/static')));
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
 app.use(app.router);
});
```

I've been trying to detect the availability of flash as so:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('FLASH: ', req.flash);
    ....
```

My logs show the following:

```
FLASH:  undefined
FLASH:  undefined
FLASH:  function _flash(type, msg) {....
```

This was displayed with just one request to the '/' route.  I understand why there may be multiple requests with the one `GET` request to '/', however, I'm wondering why `req.flash` is not available on every request as the docs state.

Comment: Are your first two requests for static files? I haven't used req.flash, but it's probably that it's not available for your static handler. Move your `flash()` middleware before the static middleware, or possibly remove the wildcard on your root route?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what it must be.  There's a static request for favicon and an image on the page and flash isn't available on the static requests as you said.  I think that's worthy of an answer if you want to post it so.

Comment: I went ahead and added my comment as an answer. If that doesn't work, I would add debug statements to the express module to see why things aren't lining up. I like to use the same `NODE_DEBUG` conditional function that core uses [see here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L54). Replace `net` with `myapp` then, start the app with `NODE_DEBUG=maypp node index.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change your configuration to:

```
app.configure('production', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/lib/static')));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

I always keep my static route at the end of my middleware.

I think the problem is that your `/*` route is also firing for `/static` requests and, since  that middleware is declared before the `flash()` middleware, the request object hasn't yet been modified.